# How to check application status in Spring Eureka server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

In Spring Eureka server is possible to see at status column the application status. Considering this health status is provided by Spring Boot Actuator, the application should add that dependency to support it.

Once my application is started, Eureka Dashboard shows the application as UP, but if I stop the application I still can see in there the same status.

Is there any property to set in Eureka to check if application is still running and remove from there? How does it work in practice?

Comment: Depending on how eureka is setup, it may not evict those instances because it thinks there are network errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually its a feature which is trying to avoid network partition issues, when your eureka cant see servers with services, but client of eureka has connection to them.

This lack of fast de-registration was a pain for me. I was trying to tweak it, but with no luck so I just switch this feature off in eureka config (this is probably not recommended but..) :

```
eureka:
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false
```

Comment: Is there any collateral effect,  for example increasing the number of heartbeats over network?

Comment: I dont see any reason for increased number of heartbeats. But ofcourse caveat here is that your eureka will remove service instance immediately after losing connection to this particular service. At least in case of my project I wanted this behaviour.

Comment: Ok, but removing immediately isn't good? I guess keeping something useless on dashboard there's no advantages

Comment: For me removing immediately should be a default, but there are smarter guys in netflix than I am :) check https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-Eureka-Peer-to-Peer-Communication notice rule about 85%. If I understand correctly, if eureka lost connection to more that 15% of service instances, it stop deregistering them, as it may be due to  network partitioning. If you have only 3 instances of service, then if you switch off only one of them (33,3%) it stops eureka from deregistering it.

Comment: I added this property, but even stopping the service the dashboard is not updated immediately.  Another point is a constant message appeared on dashboard saying that enableSelfPreservation is disabled, is it fine?

Comment: yes, it doesnt happen immediately, i think its in some docs that it may take up to 90 seconds. Red banner will show up as netflix doesnt recommend switching this 'feature' off :)